# Cocos2d icons for universal app

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, icons

How to add icons for iphone and ipad in cocos2d for universal app?

Answer (score 2):

If you put an icon file in your resources folder in xcode and name it icon.png then that will be the icon that will appear for the user to select to run your application on the iphone/ipod/ipad.

Same goes if you put another file in the resources folder and name it default.png then it will show up as the splash screen that appears while your application is being loaded.

Note: If you are working with a template it will probably already have canned files with these names.  Just remove them from the resource folder in xcode and add the new ones.  To add the files to your project, drag them into the resource folder within xcode and select the check box for: "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)", as well as, make sure in add targets section only the check box for your application name is checked and the radio button "Recursively create groups for any added folders" is selected.  This will copy the file(s) into your project directory and they will also appear in the resources folder in xcode.  You can then click on them in xcode to see that they are correct.

As a bonus here is a link for a post talking about good places for icons and sounds too:
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104124/need-2d-iphone-graphics-designed/4111974#4111974)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Cocos2d Application from the "Cocos2d Template". it has Icon files (e.g. Icon.png,Icon-72.png etc). If you replace them with your icons, you are well to go.